# NameError: name 'nltk' is not defined

Tags: python, anaconda, nltk

I have a Python notebook that used to work before without problems.
Now if I try to run it, I get an "NameError: name 'nltk' is not defined" error.
I'm not sure what has changed since on my system.
I tried so far:

1. Installing nltk library with pip
2. Downloading nltk library with python interpreter

```sh
pip3 install nltk 

Requirement already satisfied: nltk in /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.5)

python
>>>import nltk
>>>nltk.download('all')
```

```sh
$ which python python2 python3

/Applications/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2
/Applications/anaconda3/bin/python3

$ which pip pip2 pip3

/Applications/anaconda3/bin/pip
/Applications/anaconda3/bin/pip3

$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.3

$ echo $PATH
/Applications/anaconda3/bin:/Applications/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/testimo/.rvm/bin:/Users/testimo/.rvm/bin
```

Is this path wrong? How can I fix it?
Or any other tips? Thank you!

Comment: Show `sys.path` of the notebook environment, not your terminal

Comment: Are you not using a Conda environment?